# Uploading picture in golang via Fetch API

Tags: javascript, go, fetch-api

I'm facing issue with uploading picture via Fetch API. I found few threads on stackoverflow about this problem but none of them seems to answer the question, they just explain why it is like that. I wrote the simplest example that presents this issue, in browser console it prints "SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 0" that comes from golang server not being able to read from r.FormFile("file"), which I guess means it is not even there.

EDIT:
The error on server side is:

```
request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data
```

Code below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "mime/multipart"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", UploadFile)
    http.HandleFunc("/uploadForm", uploadForm)
    log.Println("Running")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func uploadForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    htmlTemplate := `
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form action="/asdf" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="width:100%;" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
    <textarea name="content" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <input
                type="file"
                id="fileElem"
                name="file"
                accept="image/*"
                style="display:none"
                onchange="onSelectFile();"/>
        <label id="fileLabel"></label>
        <button id="fileSelect" type="button">Choose File</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
<script>
function validateForm(node) {
    var content = node.firstElementChild.value;
    if (content.length < 1) {
        alert("You cannot post empty content!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
const fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
const fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem");

fileSelect.addEventListener(
    "click", (e) => {
        if (fileElem) {
            fileElem.click();
        }
    }, false)

const input = document.getElementById('fileElem');
const onSelectFile = () => {
    document.getElementById("fileLabel").innerHTML = input.files[0].name;
    uploadFile(input.files[0]);
}
const uploadFile = (file) => {
  fetch('/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {},
    body: file // This is your file object
  }).then(
    response => response.json()
  ).then(
    success => console.log(success)
  ).catch(
    error => console.log(error)
  );
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
    `
    t := template.New("tmpl.html")
    t, _ = t.Parse(htmlTemplate)
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

// UploadFile uploads a file to the server
func UploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }

    file, handle, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    mimeType := handle.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "mime %v", mimeType)

    switch mimeType {
    case "image/jpeg":
        saveFile(w, file, handle)
    case "image/png":
        saveFile(w, file, handle)
    default:
        jsonResponse(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "The format file is not valid.")
    }
}

func saveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, file multipart.File, handle *multipart.FileHeader) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err)
        return
    }

    err = ioutil.WriteFile("./static/"+handle.Filename, data, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err)
        return
    }
    jsonResponse(w, http.StatusCreated, "File uploaded successfully!.")
}

func jsonResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, message string) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    fmt.Fprint(w, message)
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the server respond on the fetch?

Comment: @tkausl request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data